# SwiftUI - List swipe action gets stuck

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm implementing a custom bottom sheet using SwiftUI (iOS 15). I'm having an issue where the list stops responding to gestures if I hide and reopen the list with the swipe button visible.

```
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("1").swipeActions { Button(action: {}) { Text("Do!") } }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showList: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Show", isOn: $showList).toggleStyle(.button)
            if self.showList {
                ListView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Couple things I tried:

option 1: The standard SwiftUI sheet works fine but I can't use that because I need to control the height of the sheet.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Toggle("Show", isOn: $showList).toggleStyle(.button)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showList, content: {
            Toggle("Close", isOn: $showList).toggleStyle(.button)
            ListView()
        })
    }
}
```

option 2: I can hack around the issue by placing a blank view on top but when I show the list again the swipe action is still engaged so that's not ideal.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Toggle("Show", isOn: $showList).toggleStyle(.button)
        ZStack {
            ListView()
            if !self.showList {
                Text("")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: on iOS 16.1 simulator it works fine.

Comment: Nice! Not sure if I can upgrade anytime soon but that could be an option in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally. Embedding the List inside a NavigationView fixes the problem.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("1")
                    .swipeActions {
                        Button(action: {}) { Text("Do!") }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
}
```